# Create a textfield which only supports copy-option

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, copy

Is there a way to make a textfield (EditText, TextView) on Android which displays copyable text (no edit options)? Something like Swing's JTextField().setEditable(false) on Windows?

Edit: It seems that my question was a little bit unclear, so I'm going to give it some real-world context. I am working on a checksum calculator which lets you pick a file and prints the results of the calculation into 4 different textfields. I want the user to be able to copy those hashes from the textfield, but to disable all edit options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are asking is very straightforward and simple, if I am reading your question wrong, please correct me!
Are the four text fields that hold the results required to be EditText 's?

otherwise - >

Question:
**How to make TextView only copyable, not editable**

Answer:
Well using a TextView solves the ***not editable*** part
and if you take a look
at my android studio. I have a simple TextView with an attribute of
   `textIsSelectable="true"`   
allowing users to copy and paste!
[image: Layout File containing only 1 TextView, set to textIsSelectable="true"]

Hope this helped!

-Stephen

Comment: Awesome! glad I could help